# Can't change boot order on Lenovo L13 Yoga - BIOS isn't locked

Tags: ubuntu, bios, uefi

I have a ThinkPad L13 Yoga, which I like quite a bit

Earlier in the week, I booted it off of a Live Ubuntu disk to make a full Ubuntu installation on a USB drive. That worked flawlessly

However, a new option, called 'ubuntu', has appeared in my laptop's boot order (at the very top). And, for some reason, I can't change my boot order. I checked, the Lock Boot Order option isn't enabled (in fact, I can't enable it at all, for it is grayed out).

This is a serious issue for me, as it always boots into the GRUB terminal. For context, GRUB boots into the terminal because it can't find the Ubuntu drive (I don't have it plugged in), and even when I do have it plugged in, it still dumps out to the terminal

I **do not want to dual-boot with Ubuntu. I only want Windows on this computer**
Resetting my computer is **not an option** for me

I can get out of it and boot into Windows by typing "exit", but I would like my laptop to ignore 'ubuntu' and boot straight into Windows. Any suggestions on how I can fix this mess?

Note: if there's some way to do it from Ubuntu, splendid. I'm willing to jump through some hoops if I must.
If I absolutely must, I would also be okay with somehow setting up Grub to automatically exit immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, and multiple hours of trying, I figured out how to fix this problem.

You probably can skil steps 3-5 and instead boot into Ubuntu normally. I only had to do this because the USB image was damaged somehow

Here's the steps I followed

1. Shut down, plug Ubuntu USB in, boot
2. Press ENTER on Lenovo screen, then F12. Select Ubuntu drive
3. GRUB should show up. Select "Other options"
4. Select the bottom-most recovery option
5. Wait for the Recovery prompt, then select "Boot Normally"
6. Once in Ubuntu, open the terminal
7. Run **efibootmgr**, take note of the NUMBER next to "ubuntu" (for me this was 0001)
8. Run this command, replacing "0001" with the number from the previous step: **sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -A**
9. Shut down, remove USB drive, and boot normally

Comment: Thanks for the solution. another way to fix can be efibootmgr with the --bootorder option to put the windows "number" before "ubuntu".
In my case BootOrder was 0001,0000,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001E so i did efibootmgr -bootorder 0000,0001,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001E